# Pass data to a html page opened in jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have succeeded in opening a html page in a jQuery dialogbox. I have also passed a data called 'vendorid' to it, but do not know how to retrieve it in the html page that opens.

```
            $('#btnShowSupplierStats').click(function () {
            showUrlInDialog('../supplierstats.htm?vendorId=' + $(this).attr('vendorId')); return false;
            //showUrlInDialog('../Default2.aspx'); return false;
        });

        function showUrlInDialog(url) {
            var vid = $(this).attr('vendorId')
            var tag = $("<div id='statsDiv' vid ='"+ vid +"'></div>");
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    tag.html(data).dialog({ show: "fadein", hide: "fadeout",
                    modal: true, minHeight: 550, minWidth: 800, autoOpen: false,
                    close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); }, buttons: [{
                    text: "Close", click: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); 
                    return false; } }] }).data("vendorid", vid).dialog('open'); 
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

**UPDATE**: The answer from Farrukh would do this job ( i.e. second option he mentioned, since I am using a 100% client-side approach). But I did not store the data to be passed in a hiddent field. Instead I used the following approach which also works always:

1. When you are about to open the dialog through jQuery, just before this, set the attribute for the button which is the opener of dialog. In my case, I set an attribute called 'vendorid' on this button. Let's say the id of the opener button is 'btnOpenVendorDialog'. So need to use the following code.

   $('#btnOpenVendorDialog').attr('vendorid', 'Vendor1234');
   //open your dialog here ....

2.Then, in the html page that opens in dialog window, I can easily retrieve this attribute without any problems.

```
var vid = $('#btnOpenVendorDialog').attr('vendorid');
```

**THAT's IT.  YOU ARE  ALL READY TO do** whatever you want with this passed data.

Comment: Can you change the server script so it puts the vendorId parameter in the HTML page that it creates?

Comment: How would I do that? The target html page is a full STATIC html page with no server-side interactions. And in parent page, I get vendorid from  a session variable.

Comment: If it's a static page, why are you putting a parameter in the URL? Parameters are used by server-side scripts.

Comment: I was struggling to pass data to html page in dialog box and putting the query string was an attempt in desperation. But I think that is not needed as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use server side and get the passed data in post or get(in your case vendor ID is get) and use it to populate a hidden element or data-vendorID attribute of any available element.
2. If you are using javascript then data vendorID that you have passed as vid is available after success function so place it in as a hidden input field or place it as a data-vendor-id on one of the other DOM elements and access it from there.

Comment: You mean success function for jQueryUI dialog?